# Find max value from a list that is less than another value

Tags: python, mongodb-query

I have a collection of mongodb documents that are in this format:

```
{    
    "name": "John Smith",
    "test_dates": [
        "2020-07-25",
        "2020-07-30",
        "2020-08-03",
        "2020-08-06"
    ],
    "last_tested": "2020-07-25"
}
```

`test_dates` is an optional field.  `last_tested` is required, but it may be null.

I want to perform a mongodb query in python that will find all documents where the user missed their most recent test prior to today, i.e.:

- `test_dates` is present and contains at least one date prior to today; AND
- `last_tested` is null OR is earlier than the latest `test_date` prior to today

I have working code that iterates over the entire collection and looks at the fields of each document directly, but of course this is inefficient.

I'm new to mongoDB and I have no idea how to write this query.  Help!

Comment: Which Python library are you using to query the DB?

Comment: What is the type of dates in database?

Comment: @DeepSpace I'm using PyMongo 3.5.1.

Comment: @OlvinRoght they are python `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks something like this should work

```
{
   "test_dates": {"$exists": true, "$nin": [null, [], YOU_TODAY_DATE]},
   "$or": [
       {"last_tested": {$eq: null}},
       {"last_tested": {$lte: YOU_TODAY_DATE}}
   ]
}
```

I will try to explain the query :

`$exists: true` test that your field `test_dates` exists

AND

`"$nin": [null, [], YOU_TODAY_DATE]` that it's not null, nor empty nor equal to today

AND
(

`{$eq: null}` check that it's not null

OR

`{$lte: YOU_TODAY_DATE}` last_tested should be before today
)